# How to install Apache without disturbing the existing instance?

Tags: apache, installation, rhel

I have the apache 2.2 installed in my RHEL 6.1 and I wanted to try Apache 2.4 before switching to it.

I downloaded the latest version and when I googled around for manual install, I found so many different documents. But I do not know whether my new installation will overwrite my existing apache installation..

I would like to know whether its possible to install Apache on the same maching without disturbing the existing apache service (including no changes to the system configs) ?? If yes, how can I do that?

I would like to install the latest apache with different service (say httpd2) and try it if things are working without any problems (anyway I would stop the other service when I try one).

Any suggestions or help links?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to look at this: http://developerblog.redhat.com/2014/10/01/using-apache-httpd-2-4-rhel6/

Apache 2.4 is part of Red Hat Software Collections, are Red Hat supported, and are part of the RHEL subscriptions.  Look for this in the software collections channel.